# Unparseable date exception

Tags: java, дата

Имеется следующий код:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = null;

String sDate = ""15/04/1990""
date = sdf.parse(sDate);
```

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "15/04/1990"

В чем беда?

Comment: Формат даты посмотрите внимательнее.

Comment: Во всём, начиная с того, что этот код не компилируется.

Comment: Если кто-нибудь своим ответом-таки решил вашу проблему, то не поленитесь отметить ответ "галочкой" (рядом со "стрелочками" у ответов), чтобы он не висел в списке неотвеченных :)

Answer (score 6):

Если вы ожидаете даты именно в формате вашей строковой переменной (`String sDate = "15/04/1990";`), то поменяйте ожидаемый формат данных, например.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

---

А вообще странно, что у вас не выдает ошибку компиляции на такую вот строку:

```
String sDate = ""15/04/1990""
```

поправьте на

```
String sDate = "15/04/1990";
```

Comment: mm - это минуты, надо поправить

Comment: @PavelParshin И правда, извиняюсь, подправил.